# android programming for triggering phone call

Tags: android

i have been trying this prblemstatement. when triggered with a bluetooth file transfer android phone has to make an automatic phone call to a given number .Can any help with the coding in android for this purpose.

I need code to start phone call from bluetooth like when i send data from it to phone then the phone should automatically call apredefined number.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void call() {   
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);          
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));          
            startActivity(callIntent);  
   }
```

is the function you need to call as soon as the transfer is triggered.

Comment: yes but the function has to call only after the completion of data transfer kindly help me with the code

Comment: The documentation clearly explains the different callbacks for Bluetooth connection. Go through them : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html. As soon as the socket finishes reading data from the stream, fire the call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String phone = "tel:" + "03242342342" ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
 startActivity(intent);
```

you need to add permission for that.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

or better approach to use

`Intent.ACTION_DIAL`

as intent filter in order to avoid permission, `ACTION_DIAL` will choose appropriate app for phone calling.

Comment: i need to first detect data transfer from bluetooth and then trigger the call could u please help me with the code.